# How to generate OpenAPI spec for NextJS api route handlers?

Tags: next.js, openapi, next.js13

If I have a NextJS application that uses [route handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) to define the backend API, is it possible to generate an OpenAPI spec for those routes? I'm interested in the functionality that exists in FastAPI in Python, where an API